GPCH Goldair infrared Patio Heater not working
I have a GPCH Gold Air infrared Patio Heater. It is not switching on. I replaced the tube, but is not working. Is there a wiring diagram available?

I find search usually finds stuff like that.  If not then contacting the company is the best way to find.

The wiring should not be that hard to check, power cord, switch, wires to light.  There is something on search about a remote control.  If you have a remote, that might be the problem, if the wiring is okay.
